# Same Linux command with different results

Tags: linux, centos, command

I just started using Linux and so far, I've only managed to get the server installed. My lecturer asked me the question below and I have no idea about it as I haven't experienced such. Could anyone about help me answer the question, please?
The question is as follows:
**Explain what could possibly be the problem when a command that was issued gave a different result from the last time it was used (Assume you are working on a Linux operating system environment)**

Comment: Can you give an example of what is meant by "a command that was issued" ?

Comment: Are you trying to get your homework done by us ?

Comment: By that, he means that a certain command was used twice but the output results were different ie. the first result and second result was different.

Comment: @Carpette:  There is a "homework" policy that says... "Homework is OK to ask, just be honest about it.  I think it's important to encourage new GNU/Linux users.

Comment: @Carpette, haha, not really. I just wanted to know what could be the reason why the output results were different. Still new to linux and I'm actually learning the module on my own. Lecturer only gave us assignments and that was his role :D 
I'm guessing maybe the accounts used to run the commands were different like root user would show more than a normal user? 
Just a guess.. I could be wrong here

Comment: @RubberStamp, thank you :) Well, the questions given to us weren't even part of the notes he had mailed us. There are many more questions but I managed to YouTube those for a better understanding on how Linux works.

Comment: @AswathyNair:  It seems you've got at least one answer.  User accounts.  This relates to file permissions...

Comment: @AswathyNair no problem. The context of the command can have change since the last time you've used it. A simple example is `cd -` that moves you to the last folder you were before your last change, if you use it twice in a row, the result will be different each time.

Comment: @RubberStamp, thank you so much! :) I haven't run such commands, though. So far, I've only used Vi commands to configure the server (I'm using Redhat on CentOS) :) I'll research more on what you just mentioned to go deeper into that :) Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the follwing in your home directory:

```
mkdir bin
cd bin

echo "#! /bin/bash" > top
echo "echo \"Monkeys Rulez\"" >> top
chmod a+x top

cd ../

export PATH=./bin

top
```

Instead of running the `top` command (`man 1 top`: for the manual describing `top`) it will run the top file that you created in the `bin` directory in your home directory - thus depending on your search path you can be made to run a command that is not the one you are expecting.

This is my guess at what your lecturer is getting at - if you are super paranoid you always run the full path to a command, ie `/usr/bin/top` rather than just `top`.

HTH